# Indices of constant consecutive values in a matrix, and number of constant values

Tags: matlab, matrix, run-length-encoding

I have a matrix with constant consecutive values randomly distributed throughout the matrix. I want the indices of the consecutive values, and further, I want a matrix of the same size as the original matrix, where the number of consecutive values are stored in the indices of the consecutive values. For Example

```
  original_matrix = [1 1 1;2 2 3; 1 2 3];

  output_matrix = [3 3 3;2 2 0;0 0 0];
```

I have struggled mightily to find a solution to this problem. It has relevance for meteorological data quality control. For example, if I have a matrix of temperature data from a number of sensors, and I want to know what days had constant consecutive values, and how many days were constant, so I can then flag the data as possibly faulty.

temperature matrix is number of days x number of stations and I want an output matrix that is also number of days x number of stations, where the consecutive values are flagged as described above.

If you have a solution to that, please provide! Thank you.

Comment: To be consistent, shouldn't the `0`s in your `output_matrix` actually be `1`s? If consecutive values change, then there is always 1 constant consecutive value.

Comment: @hitzg Yes, that is fine, good point actually. It probably would be better to have 1's instead of 0's. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problems, I made my own utility function `runlength`:

```
function RL = runlength(M)
% calculates length of runs of consecutive equal items along columns of M

% work along columns, so that you can use linear indexing

% find locations where items change along column
jumps = diff(M) ~= 0;

% add implicit jumps at start and end
ncol = size(jumps, 2);
jumps = [true(1, ncol); jumps; true(1, ncol)]; 

% find linear indices of starts and stops of runs
ijump = find(jumps);
nrow = size(jumps, 1);
istart = ijump(rem(ijump, nrow) ~= 0); % remove fake starts in last row
istop = ijump(rem(ijump, nrow) ~= 1); % remove fake stops in first row
rl = istop - istart;
assert(sum(rl) == numel(M))

% make matrix of 'derivative' of runlength
% don't need last row, but needs same size as jumps for indices to be valid
dRL = zeros(size(jumps)); 
dRL(istart) = rl;
dRL(istop) = dRL(istop) - rl;

% remove last row and 'integrate' to get runlength
RL = cumsum(dRL(1:end-1,:));
```

It only works along columns since it uses [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). Since you want do something similar along rows, you need to transpose back and forth, so you could use it for your case like so:

```
>> original = [1 1 1;2 2 3; 1 2 3];
>> original = original.';  % transpose, since runlength works along columns
>> output = runlength(original);
>> output = output.';  % transpose back
>> output(output == 1) = 0;  % see hitzg's comment
>> output

output =

     3     3     3
     2     2     0
     0     0     0
```

Comment: works great! Now I see the solution - you need those negative 1's (-1's) following the indexes of the consecutive values so that cumsum get's "reset". Most of the run length encoding examples I've found don't return the original run length's stored in the corresponding indices. Thank you!